# Android sending information to Native Code when Android app. starts

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an Android app in Java which uses calls to native code via JNI.

Things like the touch events are being passed down to that code. But I also want to send some initialization data down to the ndk code when the applications starts or is ready to run.

I see some handlers in the ndk code I'm looking at like onStart and onSurfaceCreated but it doesn't look from those examples that I explicitly call these from Java. So I can't add extra parameters to them to pass this initialization data.

Where is it that I'd typically pass my own initialization data from Java down to native code?

Which event in the Java code? And is there an explicit event for this in NDK?

Comment: `onCreate` of the main activity would be a good place.

Comment: Are you working with NativeActivity?

Comment: re: NativeActivity, no. I don't think so. I'm basically adapting an example I got from the Oboe library tutorial (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/musicalgame-using-oboe/index.html#0)

Comment: You can add modify the native hooks then, e.g. add the missing details to onStart() native method.

Comment: But I don't seem to be the one calling onStart. So how would I add the parameters to it?